# How can I sort or add an item to a UITableView the opposite way?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So, I have an `UITableView` which holds entries for an app I am making. The `entriesViewController` is its own class, with a **.xib** file. I have a button that adds a new item.

It does this with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)newItem:(id)sender {
    LEItem *newItem = [[LEItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
    NSLog(@"New Item = %@", newItem);
    [TableView reloadData];
}
```

Now this works, and adds the item, however it puts it at the bottom of the list. Since this app logs things for days, I do not want the items in this order. The newest items should be placed at the top of the list. How do I do this? I didn't see any easy way to add items to the table view at the top, but I might be missing something pretty basic.

This doesn't seem like it should be hard, I am probably just overlooking something.

Ideas are welcome.

**Edit:**

Here is `LEItem` Store:

```
//
//  LEItemStore.m
//
//  Created by Josiah Bruner on 10/16/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Infinite Software Technologies. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LEItemStore.h"
#import "LEItem.h"

@implementation LEItemStore
+ (LEItemStore *)sharedStore
{
    static LEItemStore *sharedStore = nil;
    if (!sharedStore)
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];

    return sharedStore;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self sharedStore];
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];
        allItems = [NSKeyedUnarchiver  unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

        if (!allItems)
        {
            allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSArray * )allItems
{
    return allItems;
}
-(LEItem *)createItem
{
    LEItem *p = [LEItem addNewItem];

    [allItems addObject:p];

    return p;
}

- (void)removeItem:(LEItem *)p
{
    [allItems removeObjectIdenticalTo:p];
}

-(void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from toIndex:(int)to
{
    if (from == to) {
        return;
    }
    LEItem *p = [allItems objectAtIndex:from];

    [allItems removeObjectAtIndex:from];

    [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:to];
}

- (NSString *)itemArchivePath {
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"item.archive"];
}

-(BOOL)saveChanges {
    NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];

    return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:allItems toFile:path];
}
@end
```

Comment: Is this cocoa or cocoa touch, they have very different ways of going about makin tables.

Comment: As seen from the tags, this is Cocoa.

Comment: Yes but he's got ***UI***TableView in the title.  I'm going to retag this with [cocoa-touch]

Comment: Opps. Sorry, yeah, it was suppose to be Cocoa Touch. Messed that one up pretty big.

Comment: Post some of LEItemStore please.

Comment: Show us your implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the simplest solution would be to modify `-[LEItemStore createItem]` to this:

```
-(LEItem *)createItem {
    LEItem *p = [LEItem addNewItem];
    [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:0];    
    return p;
}
```

Comment: That makes the most sense. Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Well, I wish I could un-upvote. That did not work at all. It does create an item at the top, however it duplicates the item at the bottom of the list. Then, if you try to delete anything, it throws an exception. I am guessing this is because you are moving that item, but the others aren't going anywhere, therefore causing problems.

Comment: Anyway, I solved the problem. Thanks for the attempt though. :)

Comment: You can un-upvote. Just click the up-arrow again. It's a toggle.

Comment: Okay... It did work. Not sure what I did wrong the first time.

Comment: Me too. I'm just hitting myself for not knowing why it didn't work before. My guess is that I just typed the wrong thing in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even without rearrange the array internally.If you implement the data source and you define this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Assuming that in your array the oldest objects are at the lowest indexes,supposing that your table view has M rows, return a cell with the format of the object at index M-rowIndex-1.

Comment: Sorry, mate, but this is for UIKit.  I know you had good intentions.

Comment: except that this is UIKit we are working with. I messed up the tags originally.

Comment: You should say how you solved the problem, if none of these answers solved the problem, answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, after you create the new item, instead of using

```
[allItems addObject:p];
```

you just need:

```
[allItems insertObject:p atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any type of createdDate or other sortable property on the item? Simply sort your retained list of items (or NSFetchedResultsController) or whatever you are binding to by that property.

Comment: Yes, LEItem has an NSDate *dateCreated property. How would I use that to sort by?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the comparison mechanism in your LEItem class, and have it compare dates easily:

```
-(NSComparisonResult)compare:(LEItem*)otherItem {
     return [self.dateCreated compare:otherItem.dateCreated];
}
```

Then, it's just a matter of using `sortArrayUsingSelector:` with the selector `compare:`.